# Python 3 - function data member of class

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a class which should call subprocess.call to run a script as part of it's job.

I've defined the class in a module and at the top of the module I have imported the call function from subprocess.

I am not sure whether I should just use call() inside one of the functions of the class or whether I should make it a data member and then call it via the self.call function object.

I would prefer the latter but I'm not sure how to do this. Ideally I would like not to have subprocess at the top and have something like:

```
class Base:
    def __init__():
        self.call = subprocess.call
```

but the above doesn't work. How would you go about doing this? I'm very new to Python 3.

Comment: Why do you need to store the `call` function at all?

Comment: How does this fail for you? `Base().call('echo')` works for me. Did you mean to forget to specify the `self` parameter in the `__init__(self)` method signature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean that you want:

```
import subprocess

class Base:
    def __init__(self):  #don't forget `self`!!!
        self.call = subprocess.call

instance = Base()
print (instance.call(['echo','foo']))
```

---

Although I would really prefer:

```
import subprocess

class Base:
    call = staticmethod(subprocess.call)
    def __init__(self):
        self.call(["echo","bar"])

instance = Base()
print (instance.call(['echo','foo']))
```

---

Finally, if you don't need to have `call` as part of your API for the class, I would argue it's better to just use `subprocess.call` within your methods.

Comment: You could also use `__call__ = staticmethod(subprocess.call)` and then `instance(['echo','foo'])`